# Compare 2 list of object and if the name matches, I want to get the values associated with it or else, give it a 0

Tags: python-3.x

So I have 2 lists:

```
list_1 = ['BANK OF AMERICA, NATIONAL ASSOCIATION', 'WELLS FARGO & COMPANY', 'JPMORGAN CHASE & CO.', 'U.S. BANCORP', \
'SCOTTRADE BANK', 'CITIBANK, N.A.', 'PNC Bank N.A.', 'CAPITAL ONE FINANCIAL CORPORATION', 'SUNTRUST BANKS, INC.', 'Paypal Holdings, Inc']

list_2 = [["CAPITAL ONE FINANCIAL CORPORATION", 62],["CITIBANK, N.A.", 78],["JPMORGAN CHASE & CO.", 167], \
["Paypal Holdings, Inc", 56], ["SCOTTRADE BANK", 81],["SUNTRUST BANKS, INC.", 57],["U.S. BANCORP", 83],["WELLS FARGO & COMPANY", 179]]
```

List_1 is the master list which will not change and List_2 does not have BANK OF AMERICA, NATIONAL ASSOCIATION and PNC Bank N.A.. Anyway I want to compare both lists and if the name matches, I want to get the values of the list in the order of list_1. If the name is not in list_2, then it will put a 0 instead.

This is the example output output:

```
[0, 179, 167, 83, 81, 78, 0, 62, 57, 56]
```

Comment: why is the output not `[0, 0, 179...]` if both bank of america and national association both are not there in list 2

Comment: It's 'bank of america, national association'. The whole thing is the bank's name

Comment: i see. Are you restricted to data type being list only here? This becomes lot more easier if its a dict

Comment: list_1 and list_2 are the results I got after I queried it using sqlalchemy but i'm open if you wish to change it to a dict. As long as the output is in a list, should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not restirtced to datatype being list here then you can convert your list_2 to a dict and this becomes a lot more easier:

```
>>> dict_list_2 = {x[0]:x[1] for x in list_2}
>>> d = []
>>> for x in list_1:
...   d.append(dict_list_2.get(x, 0))
...
>>> d
[0, 179, 167, 83, 81, 78, 0, 62, 57, 56]
>>>
```